# How to get data from multiple categories in many-to-many pattern structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, get, many-to-many

I am working with c# mvc using database first
I have 3 tables

*Table Name (columns)*

Blog (Id, BlogName, Categori_Id(*i don't use this for now*)),

Category (Id, CatagoryName),

MultiBlogCat (Blog_Id(*Primary Key*), Category_Id(*Primary Key*))

But "MultiBlogCat" Table does not appear in model.edmx, I cannot get data.

How can I get data from a "Course" table with linq in multiple categories.

Comment: `Categories.Where(..here select multiple cats..).SelectMany(c=>c.Multi...).Select(m=>m.Course)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Entity Framework? If so, EF is probably just creating collection associations on the Blob and Category classes. EF would then manage the many-to-many relationship table behind the scenes.

nHibernate probably does the same, though I'm not familiar with that particular ORM.